# Why useEffect warns for the fields that I do not need to put in the dependencies array?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have gone through the `useEffect` documentation and I do not understand why I get warning for every variable and function that I use inside `useEffect`, but I have no dependency on them.

Consider my `useEffect` here

```js
const [updatedComm, setUpdatedComm] = useState<ICommunication>(props.comm)
const [isEditOn, setIsEditOn] = useState<boolean | false>(false)
const getPublishedComm = () => { /* function implementation */ }
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
        if (!isEditOn && updatedComm !== props.comm) {
            const publishedComm = getPublishedComm()
            dispatch(editCommunication(publishedComm))
            setCurrentComm(publishedComm)
        }
    }, [isEditOn])
```

My only need to run this effect is when `isEditOn` changes. However, this code logs warnings

```sh
  Line 66:8:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'dispatch', 'getPublishedComm', 'props.comm', and 'updatedComm'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

What can I do to remove these warnings, or am I really missing something fundamentally?

Please help me understand.

Thank you

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: @DaveNewton That doesn't explain exhaustive dependencies at all.

Comment: [exhaustive deps rule](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920) provides a warning for possible [stale closures](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/#3-stale-closures-of-hooks). You can turn the rule off for that line or file `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Comment: @HMR I guess I read it differently (having been directed there by the link in the ESLint plugin page); for me it seemed to sum up the issues fairly well. The stale closure issue seems like it'd be self-explanatory (at least in my head it makes sense) since the conditional makes use of values that may change since they're created per-render.

Answer (score 0):

Do this to "silence" that warning,
especially if you're certain re-rendering should/shall be/is based on specific `dependencies`

```js
useEffect(() => {
   if (!isEditOn && updatedComm !== props.comm) {
      const publishedComm = getPublishedComm();
      dispatch(editCommunication(publishedComm));
      setCurrentComm(publishedComm);
   }
   // eslint-disable-next-line
}, [isEditOn])
```

But from what I see, even `updatedComm` should part of that `array of dependencies`.
It's worth understanding the [essence of the array of dependencies](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) as regards performance optimization by skipping effects.

Answer (score 0):

Because useEffect sees your usage of states, and state-setters, it's concerned that you have **many changing things** inside callback, but you using little dependencies.

Because in Functional component, function handler is also changed in new render

What you could do is - extract body of effect to avoid warning

**But it's strongly unrecommended** - if you feel like you doing something wrong, that's probably true, read docs again

```
function editChanged (isEditOn) { // only isEditOn guaranteed to be fresh
   if (!isEditOn && updatedComm !== props.comm) {
      const publishedComm = getPublishedComm();
      dispatch(editCommunication(publishedComm));
      setCurrentComm(publishedComm);
   }
}

useEffect(() => {
   editChanged(isEditOn)
}, [isEditOn])
```